# Search seems to be almost completely broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Advanced searches such as `closed:yes` and `user:me` are returning no results or the wrong results. I'm pretty sure there are closed questions on MSE, for example:

[image: 0 results for closed:yes]

And these aren't my posts:

[image: 16 results for user:me]

Even a [search for help](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Help) returns no results.

Also it just seems kinda slow, even when it works.

Comment: It appears to be case sensitive. You can tell by the "search options" not including "closed" for the closed search.

Comment: @KevinB And what case works for you? I tried lowercase, Sentence, and CAPS and none of them work. And it used to work before today.

Comment: The "Newest" tab for all searches seems to also be broken.

Comment: lowercase (as shown in the tips) works *fine* for me on the relevance tab, which seems to be default for me.

Comment: Or actually, it's not just the "Newest" tab.  All searches seem to be sporadically sometimes not working for me.

Comment: Not only is the advanced search you describe also not working for me (e.g., on StackOverflow), but also for the questions I've tagged (e.g., on Mathematics). It was working fine, but just stopped now a few minutes ago.

Comment: yeah, Search also not working for me in the past few minutes. I was able to get results in the "most relevant" tab, but not in the newest, then vice versa

Comment: And now it's working again as far as I can tell… Anyone else still having problems?

Comment: Have you tried `closed:yes randomizedresults:no`?

Comment: @Laurel It's also now started working properly for me again, in both of the cases I referenced previously.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Someone reported the [same thing on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427088/6083675). It's probably a different symptom of the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for the report, we deployed some changes at 19:13 UTC. We started to see service degradation in our monitoring software and began investigating internally. At 19:38 UTC we opted to roll back the breaking change which restored search functionality.

Comment: And added some kind of regression test?

Comment: Our tests didn't catch this due to difficulty scaling the test environments to the same levels of the prod environment.